# how to check multidimensional array for duplicated value

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

i have this array and i don't want to remove duplicated values..
i want to check if there are duplicates in the first value or not

> ( [0] => 1500,[0] => 1111,  [0] => 1500)

if there are then return true else return false how to do this ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1500
            [1] => first
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 50
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1111
            [1] => second
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 10
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1500
            [1] => third
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 100
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
        )



)
```

Comment: What did you tried to do?

Comment: And by "duplicates in the first value", can you clarify that what you want to know is "are there multiple sub-arrays having the same value for `[0]`"?

Comment: yes like the first array and the third

Comment: Do you have PHP 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.5+ available, the function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) makes it easy to extract the first "column" of  the sub-arrays, and feed the resultant array to `array_count_values()`, which would produce an array of values like `[1500] => 2, [1111] => 1`, from which you can easily deduce which have `> 1`.

That would look like:

```
// PHP 5.5+ only...
// Gets counts of each first sub-array value
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($input_multidimensional_array, 0));
// Test that the array key has > 1

// To check a specific one for duplicates:
if (isset($counts['1500']) && $counts['1500'] > 1) {
   // Yes, it has duplicates.
}
```

**But...** Since you do not have PHP 5.5+, you'll have to use some form of loop.

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($input_multidimensional_array as $sub_array) {
  // A temporary array holds all the first elements
  $temp[] = $sub_array[0];
}
// Count them up
$counts = array_count_values($temp);

// Then use the same process to check for multiples/duplicates:
if (isset($counts['1500']) && $counts['1500'] > 1) {
   // Yes, it has duplicates.
}
```

In either of those cases, you could also use `array_filter()` to only return the array from `$counts` which had multiples.

```
// Filter to only those with > 1 into $only_duplicates
$only_duplicates = array_filter($counts, function($v) {
  return $v > 1;
});
// To further reduce this only to the _values_ themselves like 1500, 1111
// use array_keys:
$only_duplicates = array_keys($only_duplicates);
// is now array('1500')
```

Comment: I DONT KNOW THIS VALUE $counts['1500'] BECAUSE IT IS DYNAMIC ARRAY

Comment: That's okay. If you just want to know _which_ ones are duplicates without querying for specific ones, skip the `if (isset($counts....))` and just use the `array_filter($counts....)` at the end.